# I am getting an error when applying transaction in AGGRID

Tags: ag-grid

I am trying to remove row from ag-grid using the below code. But getting an error which not at all referencing my code. Please help me to get through this. I will post screenshot the error.

```
gridOptions.api.forEachNode(function(rowNode) {
                   if(rowNode.data.Id == dataObject.Id && dmlType=="deleted"){
                         var rowToRemove = rowNode;
                         console.log('rowToRemove=====>',rowToRemove)
                         gridOptions.api.applyTransaction({ remove: rowToRemove });
                        //gridOptions.api.aappl.splice(rowNode.data.Id, 1)
                        
                    }
                });
```

[image: I am getting an error like this]
Not sure what this issue is all about. Please help.

Comment: which version of ag-grid are you using? can you produce a stackblitz link for same?

Comment: @ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules@25.1.0/

Comment: Sorry. I don't have a reproducible step.

Comment: I dont think you should remove rows while you are looping over it. First finish loop and store rows to delete in an array and applytransaction after loop ends.

Comment: Ok. I will try that. May I know why

Comment: @NBR ... 
When passing in data to be updated or removed, the grid will be asking:

"What row do you mean exactly by this data item you are passing?"

There are two approaches you can take: 1) Providing Row Node IDs, or 2) Using Object References.
[here is detail documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid/data-update-transactions/#identifying-rows-for-update-and-remove)